# How to solve this issue regarding Ruby gems installation?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone please tell me what does this error mean which is occuring as I'm trying to install Ruby sass to build my theme in Liferay 7? i have referred these two links to proceed with theme creation in Liferay 7.
1)http://www.azilen.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-create-theme-for-liferay-dxp-7/
2)http://www.javasavvy.com/liferay-dxp-theme-generator-tutorial/#comment-1699
I'm using Windows 10 as my OS.I'm behind our company proxy(If it might be an issue).
When I'm giving this command:

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

This error is appearing:

```
Error fetching http://rubygems.org/:
    no such name (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the issue with the company proxy, as it would not allow you to download any of the files. had a similar issue. I did the manual download from the rubygems.org and installed it. Or you can speak to your system admin to grant access.

```
http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
```

opening this link in the browser you will be able to download the gems and install it.

Comment: Thanks Chandra Kanth! I will then talk to the system admin for open network.